# Upload file async issue with jQuery forms to a WCF service

Tags: wcf, jqueryform

I need to wrap this up but not sure how :-)

Basically, I'm using jQuery forms to upload a file to a WCF REST service.

Client looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').ajaxForm(
            {
                url: '/_vti_bin/VideoUploadService/VideoUploadService.svc/Upload/theFileName',
                type: 'post'
            })
    });
</script>
<form id="fileUploadForm" name="fileUploadForm" method="post" action="/_vti_bin/VideoUploadService/VideoUploadService.svc/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="filename" />
  <input type="file" id="postedFile" name="postedFile" />
  <input type="submit" id="fileUploadSubmit" value="Do Upload" />
</form>
```

While server relevant snippets are

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Upload/{fileName}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void Upload(string fileName, Stream fileStream);

public void Upload(string fileName, Stream stream)
{
   // just write stream to disk...
}
```

Problem is that what I write to disk looks like this, not the content of the file (in my case, "0123456789"):

```
-----------------------------7dc7e131201ea
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource"

// bunch of same stuff here

-----------------------------7dc7e131201ea
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

fdfd
-----------------------------7dc7e131201ea
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="postedFile"; filename="C:\Inter\Garbage\dummy.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

0123456789
-----------------------------7dc7e131201ea--
```

Question - should I be manually parsing what I get above and extract the last part which corresponds to the uploaded file (not elegant)? Or there is a way to apply attribute, content type, whatever setting, in order to get in the stream JUST the uploaded file's content?

I'm suspect there is, but I'm missing it... any help?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 2 articles about Form file upload using ASP.NET Web API:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

ASP.NET Web API already has classes (like MultipartFormDataStreamProvider) to parse multipart requests and also to save data from them. Why not to use these classes to solve your problem

**UPD In case of .NET 3.5 code and hosting:**

Think that MultipartFormDataStreamProvider class and it's assembly aren't for .NET 3.5. In these case you should use some other library/class to parse multipart or do it manually.

Try following project (MIT license) and file HttpMultipartParser.cs from this project:

https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/http-form-parser/src

Comment: Thanks Regfor. I'm trying to solve this with WCF because scenario is a SharePoint web part talking with a backend service. Hence don't want to introduce another dependency.

Comment: You can use MultipartFormDataStreamProvider class using assembly reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll. In this case at least parser for it is enough.

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try and get back :-) UPDATE: don't think it's available for .NET Framework 3.5, on which service is hosted...

Comment: Ah so, think that these assembly is not for .NET 3.5. In these case you should use some other library/class to parse multipart or do it manually. Try following project (MIT license) https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/http-form-parser/src and file HttpMultipartParser.cs from this project

Comment: Yeah, ended up using http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/. Known issue is about handling multifile uploads, but I'll tackle that later on. Still, if there's a way to not needing to parse the form submission, that would be AWESOME. Thanks Regfor for your help!

Comment: There is no other way. Manually or with help or these classes (multiparses or posted by me) or may be some external projects have multipart parsing, may be RestSharp. But actally these classes are pretty easy and as I know there is no known library for that. When in .NET 4 then MultipartFormDataStreamProvider. By the way - source code for this class is opened, therefore "ideas" could be reused in your own code. And speaking about concurrent upload - it could be easily handled externally, when multiparses fits your need then use it and make some "locking" externally